# Net::FTPSSL Perl module rename does not work

Tags: perl, ftp

I'm using the Perl module Net::FTPSSL and 'rename' does not work, everything else does.
I've verified the file is there and I can rename it using gui based ftp client but not through the Perl module.

```
>>> RNFR ftpbogus.txt, testfile.txt
<<< 550 RNFR command failed.
```

Below is the code.

```
use Net::FTPSSL;
use Test::More;

my $server = "localhost";
my $ftps = Net::FTPSSL->new("localhost",
Port => 990,
Encryption => 'E',
Debug => 5);

$ftps->login("ftpuser55", "narfnarf");


## copying a file to the user's home directory.
$ftps->put("ftpbogus.txt");

my @ret = $ftps->list();

## renaming a file in the ftp server
$ftps->rename("ftpbogus.txt, testfile.txt");



#$ftps->quit();
```

Comment: Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it appears to relate programming. It may be on topic for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) but please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`rename` [takes two arguments](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/libnet-1.22/Net/FTP.pm#rename): `OLDNAME, NEWNAME`.  You're passing a single string with both filenames, the command should read

```
$ftps->rename("ftpbogus.txt", "testfile.txt");
```